# 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable - openCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am facing an error when trying to run the same code in new jupyter notebook

I am practicing on Hand gesture code, sometimes able to run code and when I try t run the same code in new notebook it is showing an error

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while capture.isOpened():    
    ret, frame = capture.read()
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (100, 100), (300, 300), (0, 255, 0), 0)
    crop_image = frame[100:300, 100:300]   
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(crop_image, (3, 3), 0)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)




TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-5-fc124576a5ed> in <module>
 14     # Get hand data from the rectangle sub window
 15     cv2.rectangle(frame, (100, 100), (300, 300), (0, 255, 0), 0)
 ---> 16     crop_image = frame[100:300, 100:300]
 17 
 18     # Apply Gaussian blur

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens sometimes when the current kernal fails. Try restarting the kernal before running the code.

Alternatively, you can use the imutils python module for accessing a video stream, it works pretty well in my experience.

pip install command:

```
pip install imutils
```

Hope this helps, goodluck.

Comment: Thank you very much Dylan Freeman, after I restart my Kernal I get another error 
Below is my code and error:

drawing = np.zeros(crop_image.shape, np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours (drawing, [contour], -1, (0,255,0), 0)
cv2.drawContours (drawing, [hull], -1, (0,0, 255), 0)

NameError --- Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-fc124576a5ed> in <module>
     97     # Show required images
     98     cv2.imshow("Gesture", frame)
---> 99     all_image = np.hstack((drawing, crop_image))
    100     cv2.imshow('Contours', all_image)
NameError: name 'drawing' is not defined

Comment: @Srikanth Hi there. Could you please show your entire code, and format it according to the rules of stack overflow i.e with code blocks separate from text etc.

Comment: I will do it. Thank you very much for prompt reply.